# JDBC thin driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc

The question I have is why does Oracle SQL developer does not require Oracle client installed on local?? I searched on the internet and found that it makes use of JDBC thin driver. Can someone please throw some light on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle thin driver is a so-called JDBC Type 4 driver, which is implemented purely in Java without native dependencies (.dll/.so), and has a full implementation of the Oracle wire protocol. In other words the thin driver does not require the Oracle client installed, as it doesn't use it.

There are also JDBC Type 2 drivers which do use native dependencies; Oracle has a Type 2 driver as well which is known as the Oracle JDBC OCI driver. This driver uses a JDBC url that is prefixed with `jdbc:oracle:oci:`.

The Type 1 and Type 3 drivers I ignore because they are hardly relevant these days.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ☺